# Serving PDF from Google Cloud Storage with get_serving_url

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, google-cloud-storage

I need to serve PDF files stored in Google Cloud Storage.

I tried:

```
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import images
bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/bucket/pdfobject')
url = images.get_serving_url(bkey)
```

This works well in the dev server, but when deployed to GAE, gives this error:
`get_serving_url_hook\n    raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)\n', 'TransformationError\n']`

I also tried:

```
url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key=None, secure_url=True, filename='/gs/bucket/pdfobject')
```

Same problem. Works in dev but `TransformationError` when deployed.

Comment: a PDF is not an image, you can't "transform" it which is what the images api is concerned with. You are doing it wrong. Either get the data from GCS directly and serve it via your app or give the user a link to the file and arrange permissions accordingly. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control

Comment: or use a signed url: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, this was it, thanks. If you want to answer the question, I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: I ran into the same issues with .csv files and I did what @PaulCollingwood recommended. I essentially linked to my bucket directly and made the reading permissions public. The public url is of the form `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket_name>/<file_name>`